# How to prevent repetition of randomly generated options in C++?

Tags: c++

Here is what I have done so far, I did my best to label each bit of the code. It should also be noted that this was written in XCode, so it's running on a Mac.

```
/*
Ayush Sharma
4 November 2016
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main (){

//clearing the screen
system("clear");

//seeding the random
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

//variables & arrays
char answer;
int r, m, correct = 0;
string capitals[50] =
    {"Montgomery", "Juneau", "Phoenix", "Little Rock", "Sacramento", "Denver", "Hartford", "Dover", "Tallahassee", "Atlanta", "Honolulu", "Boise", "Springfield", "Indianapolis", "Des Moines", "Topeka", "Frankfort", "Baton Rouge", "Augusta", "Annapolis", "Boston", "Lansing", "St. Paul", "Jackson", "Jefferson City", "Helena", "Lincoln", "Carson City", "Concord", "Trenton", "Santa Fe", "Albany", "Raleigh", "Bismarck", "Columbus", "Oklahoma City", "Salem", "Harrisburg", "Providence", "Columbia", "Pierre", "Nashville", "Austin", "Salt Lake City", "Montpelier", "Richmond", "Olympia", "Charleston", "Madison", "Cheyenne"};
string states[50] = {"Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Carolina","North Dakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"};

//title
cout << "***************************************************************\n";
cout << "*                                                             *\n";
cout << "*                 United States Capitals Quiz                 *\n";
cout << "*                                                             *\n";
cout << "***************************************************************\n\n";



for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    //Picking A Random State
    r = rand() % 50;
    //Checking if State is a Repeat
    if (states[r] != "-1") {
        cout << "What is the capital of " << states[r] << "? ";
        //Picking Correct Answer Choice and Respective Layout
        m = rand() % 4;
        if (m == 0) {
            cout << "\nA: " << capitals[r] << endl;
            cout << "B: " << capitals[rand()%50] << endl;
            cout << "C: " << capitals[rand()%50] << endl;
            cout << "D: " << capitals[rand()%50] << endl;
        }
        if (m == 1) {
            cout << "\nA: " << capitals[rand()%50] << endl;
            cout << "B: " << capitals[r] << endl;
            cout << "C: " << capitals[rand()%50] << endl;
            cout << "D: " << capitals[rand()%50] << endl;
        }
        if (m == 2) {
            cout << "\nA: " << capitals[rand()%50] << endl;
            cout << "B: " << capitals[rand()%50] << endl;
            cout << "C: " << capitals[r] << endl;
            cout << "D: " << capitals[rand()%50] << endl;
        }
        if (m == 3) {
            cout << "\nA: " << capitals[rand()%50] << endl;
            cout << "B: " << capitals[rand()%50] << endl;
            cout << "C: " << capitals[rand()%50] << endl;
            cout << "D: " << capitals[r] << endl;
        }
        //Recieving Answer
        cout << "Answer: ";
        cin >> answer;

        //Converting Letter to Number
        if (answer == 'A' || answer == 'a') answer = 0; if (answer == 'B' || answer == 'b') answer = 1;
        if (answer == 'C' || answer == 'c') answer = 2; if (answer == 'D' || answer == 'd') answer = 3;

        //Comparing Answer to Correct Answer
        if (m == answer) {
            cout << "Correct!" << endl << endl;
            correct++;
        }else{
            cout << "Incorrect! The correct answer was " << capitals[r] << "! \n\n";
        }

        //Removing State from Array
        states[r] = "-1";

    }else{
        //If State was a Repeat, generate another State
        i--;
    }
}

//Printing Results
cout << "Number Correct: " << correct << "/15 or " << ((correct/15.00)*100) << "%!\n";

return 0;
}
```

The code works, almost. The problem is that answers are sometimes being repeated, such as in the scenario:
What is the capital of Wisconsin?
A. Madison 
B. Frankfort 
C. Jackson 
D. Madison
Only A or D is the "correct" answer despite both having the same text (altough I'd rather make it impossible for the answers to repeat). I also would like to know if there is a more efficient way to create the layout of multiple choice questions. Thanks in advance!

-Ayush

Comment: Try a while loop perhaps that checks for repeats?

Comment: There's nothing OS specific in here, so avoid talking about that. It's not relevant. It's also time to read up on the `switch` statement.

Comment: One thing to note: Using [`rand()` is considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces actually random values. Your use of `time(NULL)` as a random number seed means that this will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is [*barely* random at all](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty obvious thing to happen. An easy solution would be to make an array to hold the options already displayed. Use a while loop to add unique options to the array.You could check whether there is any repetition in the array using another function. Then, display `capitals[r]` along with three other options from the array.

```
bool noRepeat(int arr[], int o){
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if(arr[i] == o)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

```
int main(){
    ...
    //picking correct answer and determining layout
    int m = rand()%4, n=0, y, options[3];
    if (m == 0) {
        while(n<3){
            y = rand()%50;
            if(noRepeat(options, y) && capitals[y]!=capitals[r])
                options[n++] = y;                
        }
        //display according to layout
        cout << "\nA: " << capitals[r] << endl;
        cout << "B: " << capitals[options[0]] << endl;
        cout << "C: " << capitals[options[1]] << endl;
        cout << "D: " << capitals[options[2]] << endl;
    }
    //do the same for the rest
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that there are `50` values you want to draw from at random, without repetition, simply create an array or vector containing those values, shuffle it, and then access the elements of the shuffled array in order.

In C++11, this is easy using algorithms `std::iota()` and `std::random_shuffle()` from `<algorithm>`.

```
  int value[50];
  std::iota(std::begin(value), std::end(value), 0);   //  populate array with values 0 to 49

  std::random_shuffle(std::begin(value), std::end(value));
```

Then in your outer loop, instead of `r = rand()%50` use `r=value[i]`.

`std::begin()` and `std::end()` are in standard header `<iterator>`.

The same idea can be used before C++11, but the method is a little different (C++11 didn't support `std::begin()`, `std::end()` or `std::iota()`, but equivalents are easy enough to implement).

Instead of `value` being an array, I'd create it as an `std::vector<int>`, also with 50 elements.  I've illustrated above using an array, since you seem to be defaulting to using an array.

Comment: Or @Peter, put the capitals into the array (except the true answer), shuffle and pick the first three entries.

Comment: True, Philip.   The OP was generating a random index, so I illustrated how to do that.   But the idea can equally be applied to an array or vector of `std::string`s (albeit shuffling such an array potentially shuffles more data around).

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Isaiah said you can use a while loop to test for the index generated to not be same your correct answer.

Something like :

```
int index = rand() % 50;
while(index == r)
{
    index = rand() % 50;
}
cout << "B: " << capitals[index] << endl;
```

**NOTE:**  this still can produce repeats of "incorrect answers", but i guess you get the point to avoid the repeats produced by `rand`. And obviously this is code is just to correct the repeats of corrects answer, you should be using `rand` at all as mentioned in comments by others.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to pick three random capitals without repeats. So here's some pseudo code.

1. Put all capitals, except the true answer into a vector
2. Generate a random index into this vector
3. Use the capital at that index, and erase the capital from the vector
4. Repeat Steps 2 and 3 for the second and third random capitals. Note the random index should allow for the reduced vector size on each iteration.